# Rolling window groupby on panel data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

The goal is to perform a grouped rolling-window calculation on panel data. If possible, avoiding the use of `apply` and similar functions that perform slowly when there are many observation groups. Consider the following longitudinal data frame of customers with monthly sales:

```
customers = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',]).rename('customer')
date_range = pd.date_range('01/2018', '01/2019', freq='M').to_period('M').rename('month')
example_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([customers, date_range]))
example_df['sales'] = (np.random.random(example_df.shape[0]) > 0.9) * (np.random.randint(1, 25, example_df.shape[0])*100)
```

---

1. Why does the following code throw an error even though month is the name of an index?

```
example_df.groupby('customer').rolling(3, on='month').sales.sum()
```

> ValueError: invalid on specified as month, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None

A workaround is using `.reset_index` to convert month to a column. To my knowledge the simplest solution, but still I am unclear why resetting the index should be necessary.

```
example_df.reset_index('month').groupby('customer').rolling(3, on='month').sales.sum()
```

---

2. I have found that the following code performs the operation correctly, but creates a new level in the multiindex. Why does it do that?

```
example_df.groupby('customer').rolling(3).sales.sum()
```

The workaround would be to assign just the `.values`, but ignoring the index might not always be practical. For example:

```
example_df['rolling_sum'] = example_df.groupby('customer').rolling(3).sales.sum().values
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, you don't have to ignore the whole index, you can just [`droplevel(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
example_df.groupby('customer').rolling(3).sales.sum().droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
customer  month  
a         2018-01       NaN
          2018-02       NaN
          2018-03       0.0
          2018-04       0.0
          2018-05       0.0
          2018-06       0.0
          2018-07       0.0
...
```

Comment: This method seems useful to know about, thanks! Any idea why the extra level is created in the first place?

Comment: Not sure why, I believe using `group_keys=False` should prevent that, but it isn't, unfortunately…